# How do I configure my watch to display the full numerical date 3/11/17 instead of just the small date "Sat 11" or "Mar 11"

Tags: apple-watch

Just like the title:

How do I configure my watch to display the full numerical date 3/11/17 instead of just the small date "Sat 11" or "Mar 11"

I have viewed all the available complication and scoured for additional settings but the only options I see are large form "Mar 11" and small form "Sat 11"